# Combine two tables with a LEFT JOIN in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have two tables

**table1**

```
+-------+-------+
| NAME  | PRICE |
+-------+-------+
| ITEM1 |  100  |
+-------+-------+
| ITEM2 |  200  |
+-------+-------+
| ITEM3 |  300  |
+-------+-------+
```

**table2** repeats ITEM1 and ITEM2

```
    +-------+--------+---------+
    | NAME  | SUFFIX | CODE    |
    +-------+--------+---------+
    | ITEM1 | 1      | ITEM1_1 |
    +-------+--------+---------+
    | ITEM1 | 2      | ITEM1_2 |
    +-------+--------+---------+
    | ITEM2 | 1      | ITEM2_1 |
    +-------+--------+---------+
```

How can I do this result whit mySQL?

```
+-------+-------+----------+
| NAME  | PRICE |   NAME2  |
+-------+-------+----------+
| ITEM1 |  100  |  ITEM1   |
+-------+-------+----------+
| ITEM2 |  200  |  ITEM2   |
+-------+-------+----------+
| ITEM3 |  300  |  NULL    |
+-------+-------+----------+
```

I want to get elements from table1 which is *not* in table2. In this case the element I want to get is ITEM3. Can I do this with LEFT JOIN?

Comment: either you provided a wrong result set or u wrote something else.

you want everything from table1 and only the ones which are not present in table2 ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Select * from table1 s Left join table2 as t on s.NAME=t.NAME where t.NAME IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from table1 t1
left outer join table2 t2 on t1.name = t2.name
where t2.name is null
```